# Agents not leaving the queue before a transporter is free

Tags: queue, anylogic

in my model I have a queue were multiple agents from different sources come together to seize an transporter ( see picture). But now they leave immediately after they enter the queue to the seize transporter block. But I want to keep them in to queue until a transporter is free and then the first one in the queue should seize a transporter and so should move to the seize transporter block. How should I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways:

1. After the queue, add a RestrictedArea elements to limit the number of agents in the Seize seizeTransporter4 element. In the queue, you can sort the agents.
2. Instead of a queue element, use a Wait element, in which case you need to write the logic for extracting agents and sending them to seizeTransporter4 element.

The second way is more flexible in terms of writing logic.

Answer (score 1):

seizeTransporter has its own embedded queue. You can access that value with `seizeTransporter4.size()`. If you insist on having them separately, instead of queue, use delay block, with stopDelay option. Whenever the `seizeTransporter4.size()` drops below number of available transporters, run the stop delay function. Like

```
if (seizeTransporter4.size()<=3){
myDelay.stopDelay(myDelay.get(0));
}
```

Comment: But what if I want to add dispatching policy, that some orders will be put in front of the other orders in the queue? is the only possibility than to use the task priority section (in seize transporter), where I just hand code some policy? and otherwise seize transporter is fifo?

Comment: Yes, look at the Priority section in the seizeTransporter block; if your logic more complex, code your own priority. Otherwise default is FIFO.